# `os.system` yields a multiple of 256?

Tags: python

In python2, I have the following

```
>>> os.system('exit 1')
256
>>> os.system('python -c "import sys; sys.exit(125)"')    
32000
```

Why are these multiples of 256?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://legacy.python.org/search/hypermail/python-1994q2/0407.html, the value returned is the result of the `wait` function and not the actual exit status.  Specifically in that email chain, the claim is that the Perl `system` function has a little more documentation, indicating that one should divide by 256.